Unable to extract parameters
I'm trying to extract the gait parameters from a JSON file in a network drive. The code which i use is mentioned below but everytime i run it, i receive an empty dataframe. What changes can be done for the code to run?
extract_data_from_json is used to Reads JSON data from a file and returns it in a consistent format.
calculate_step_length_and_width is used to Extracts step_length and step_width from a dictionary (entry).
gaitsession_etl1 is used to perform ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) operations on gait metrics data.
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def extract_data_from_json(filename):
    """Extract data from a JSON file."""
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)  # Load JSON data
            # Debug: Check if data is a dictionary or list
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return [data]  # Wrap dictionary in a list for consistency
            elif isinstance(data, list):
                return data  # Return list directly if JSON data is a list
            else:
                print(f"Unexpected JSON data type in file {filename}: {type(data)}")
                return []
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON file {filename}: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred with file {filename}: {e}")
    return []

def calculate_step_length_and_width(entry):
    """Calculate step length and width from entry data."""
    # Placeholder logic for calculation; replace with actual logic
    step_length = entry.get('step_length', np.nan)
    step_width = entry.get('step_width', np.nan)
    return step_length, step_width

def gaitsession_etl1():
    # Load session data
    df = pd.read_parquet('Z:\\dataframes\\df_session.parquet.gzip')

    # Select 'Laps Walking Application' sessions
    df_s = df[df['testName'].str.contains('Laps Walking Application')]

    if df_s.empty:
        print("No sessions found with 'Laps Walking Application'.")
        return

    patient_list = df_s['patient'].tolist()
    identifier_list = df_s['identifier'].tolist()

    results = []

    for i in range(len(patient_list)):
        path = f'Z:/raw_data/COVID Study FAU/patients/{patient_list[i]}/sessions/{identifier_list[i]}/files'
        name = f'{identifier_list[i]}_gaitmetrics.json'
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        
        # Debug prints
        print(f"Debug - Constructed path: {path}")
        print(f"Debug - Constructed filename: {filename}")
        
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            data = extract_data_from_json(filename)
            
            if not data:
                print(f"No data found in file {filename}")
            
            for entry in data:
                if isinstance(entry, dict):
                    step_length, step_width = calculate_step_length_and_width(entry)
                    results.append({
                        'patient': patient_list[i],
                        'identifier': identifier_list[i],
                        'timestamp': entry.get('Timestamp', 'NaN'),
                        'step_length': step_length,
                        'step_width': step_width
                    })
                else:
                    print(f"Expected dictionary but got {type(entry)} in file {filename}")
        else:
            print(f"File not found: {filename}")
    
    data_gait = pd.DataFrame(results)

    if data_gait.empty:
        print("No data extracted. DataFrame is empty.")
    else:
        print(data_gait)

# Run the ETL function
gaitsession_etl1()

Tried the above and was expecting a dataframe with the parameters.
An example of the JSON file is given below:
{
  "Steps": [
    {
      "AverageLeaning": "0",
      "stepLengthLeft": "0",
      "stepLengthRight": "0",
      "totalStepsLeft": "0",
      "totalStepsRight": "0",
      "totalSteps": "0",
      "averageSpeed": "0",
      "totalDistance": "0",
      "totalDistanceLeft": "0",
      "totalDistanceRight": "0",
      "swingStanceRatio": "0",
      "swingStanceRatioLeft": "0",
      "swingStanceRatioRight": "0",
      "averageCadence": "0",
      "averageCadenceL": "0",
      "averageCadenceR": "0",
      "averageStepLengthL": "0",
      "averageStepLengthR": "0",
      "averageStepLength": "0",
      "singleDoubleRatio": "0",
      "singleDoubleRatioLeft": "0",
      "singleDoubleRatioRight": "0",
      "FootSide": "1",
      "nombreFreezing": "0",
      "Arm": "0",
      "ArmAverage": "0",
      "Shoulder": "0",
      "ShoulderAverage": "0",
      "StepHeightL": "1700.4410231740912",
      "StepHeightR": "1161.1989661045372",
      "ShufflingPercentageL": "NaN",
      "ShufflingPercentageR": "NaN",
      "ShufflingPercentage": "NaN",
      "Timestamp": "00:01:52.31"
    }


Please add an example of the JSON.

{"Steps":[{"AverageLeaning":"0","stepLengthLeft":"0","stepLengthRight":"0","totalStepsLeft":"0","totalStepsRight":"0","totalSteps":"0","averageSpeed":"0","totalDistance":"0","totalDistanceLeft":"0","totalDistanceRight":"0","swingStanceRatio":"0","swingStanceRatioLeft":"0","swingStanceRatioRight":"0","averageCadence":"0","averageCadenceL":"0","averageCadenceR":"0","averageStepLengthL":"0","averageStepLengthR":"0","averageStepLength":"0","singleDoubleRatio":"0"

"singleDoubleRatioLeft":"0","singleDoubleRatioRight":"0","FootSide":"1","nombreFreezing":"0","Arm":"0","ArmAverage":"0","Shoulder":"0","ShoulderAverage":"0","StepHeightL":"1700.4410231740912","StepHeightR":"1161.1989661045372","ShufflingPercentageL":"NaN","ShufflingPercentageR":"NaN","ShufflingPercentage":"NaN","Timestamp":"00:01:52.31"}

@Barmar this is an example of the JSON

Don't add it as a comment (very hard to read) - instead, [edit] your question to add it in there

Added the JSON example in the question @blurfus

It's invalid JSON, there are unbalanced brackets. Please use jsonlint.com to validate and format the JSON and repost it.

There's no step_length or step_width in the JSON, but calculate_step_length_and_width() expects them. Also, the list you want to loop over is in data[0]['Steps'], not data.

Assuming that you have already loaded your gzip file, what you need to do is:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_step_length_and_width(entry):
    """Calculate step length and width from entry data."""
    step_length = entry.get('averageStepLength', np.nan)
    step_width = entry.get('averageStepWidth', np.nan)
    return step_length, step_width

def gaitsession_etl1(json_data):

    results = []

    for key, data in json_data.items():
        print(f"Debug - Processing data for key: {key}")

        if not data:
            print(f"No data found for key {key}")
            continue
        
        patient, identifier = key.split('_', 1)
        
        for entry in data:
            if isinstance(entry, dict):
                step_length, step_width = calculate_step_length_and_width(entry)
                results.append({
                    'patient': patient,
                    'identifier': identifier,
                    'timestamp': entry.get('Timestamp', 'NaN'),
                    'step_length': step_length,
                    'step_width': step_width
                })
            else:
                print(f"Expected dictionary but got {type(entry)} for key {key}")
    
    data_gait = pd.DataFrame(results)

    if data_gait.empty:
        print("No data extracted. DataFrame is empty.")
    else:
        print(data_gait)

json_data = {
    'patient1_identifier1': [
        {
            "Timestamp": "00:01:52.31",
            "averageStepLength": 0.5,
            "averageStepWidth": 0.2
        },
    ],
    'patient2_identifier2': [
        {
            "Timestamp": "00:02:10.12",
            "averageStepLength": 0.6,
            "averageStepWidth": 0.3
        },
    ]
}


gaitsession_etl1(json_data)


which gives you
Debug - Processing data for key: patient1_identifier1
Debug - Processing data for key: patient2_identifier2
    patient   identifier    timestamp  step_length  step_width
0  patient1  identifier1  00:01:52.31          0.5         0.2
1  patient2  identifier2  00:02:10.12          0.6         0.3

So, whith the loading, it ought to look like this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_step_length_and_width(entry):
    """Calculate step length and width from entry data."""
    step_length = entry.get('averageStepLength', np.nan)
    step_width = entry.get('averageStepWidth', np.nan)
    return step_length, step_width

def gaitsession_etl1(json_data):
    df = pd.read_parquet('Z:\\dataframes\\df_session.parquet.gzip')

    df_s = df[df['testName'].str.contains('Laps Walking Application')]

    if df_s.empty:
        print("No sessions found with 'Laps Walking Application'.")
        return

    patient_list = df_s['patient'].tolist()
    identifier_list = df_s['identifier'].tolist()

    results = []

    for i in range(len(patient_list)):
        patient = patient_list[i]
        identifier = identifier_list[i]
        
        key = f'{patient}_{identifier}'
        print(f"Debug - Processing data for patient: {patient}, identifier: {identifier}")

        if key in json_data:
            data = json_data[key]

            if not data:
                print(f"No data found for key {key}")
                continue
            
            for entry in data:
                if isinstance(entry, dict):
                    step_length, step_width = calculate_step_length_and_width(entry)
                    results.append({
                        'patient': patient,
                        'identifier': identifier,
                        'timestamp': entry.get('Timestamp', 'NaN'),
                        'step_length': step_length,
                        'step_width': step_width
                    })
                else:
                    print(f"Expected dictionary but got {type(entry)} for key {key}")
        else:
            print(f"No JSON data found for key: {key}")
    
    data_gait = pd.DataFrame(results)

    if data_gait.empty:
        print("No data extracted. DataFrame is empty.")
    else:
        print(data_gait)

json_data = {
    'patient1_identifier1': [
        {
            "Timestamp": "00:01:52.31",
            "averageStepLength": "0.5",
            "averageStepWidth": "0.2"
        },
    ],
    'patient2_identifier2': [
        {
            "Timestamp": "00:02:10.12",
            "averageStepLength": "0.6",
            "averageStepWidth": "0.3"
        },
    ]
}

gaitsession_etl1(json_data)


